# Как записать в sql таблицу?

Tags: java, sql, база-данных, xml, таблицы

Я сделал парсинг xml, не могу записать данные в sql таблицу, созданную при помощи hibernate.

Вот парсер:

```
    @Controller
    public class MainController {
    @GetMapping("/")
    public String greeting() {
        return "greeting";
    }

    @GetMapping("/main")
    public String getValuteMain() {
        List<Valute> valuteValues = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            DocumentBuilder builder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
            InputStream stream = new URL("http://www.cbr.ru/scripts/XML_daily.asp").openStream();
            Document document = builder.parse(stream);
            Element valCurs = document.getDocumentElement();
            String date = valCurs.getAttribute("Date");
            NodeList valuteList = valCurs.getChildNodes();

            for (int i = 0; i < valuteList.getLength(); i++) {
                Node valute = valuteList.item(i);
                if (valute instanceof Element) {
                    Element valuteElement = (Element) valute;
                    Valute valuteObject = new Valute();
                    NodeList valuteElementList = valuteElement.getChildNodes();
                    for (int j = 0; j < valuteElementList.getLength(); j++) {
                        Node valuteProperty = valuteElementList.item(j);
                        if (valuteProperty instanceof Element) {
                            Element property = (Element) valuteProperty;
                            Text textNode = (Text) property.getFirstChild();
                            String text = textNode.getData().trim();
                            if (property.getTagName().equals("NumCode"))
                                valuteObject.setNumCode(text);
                            else if (property.getTagName().equals("CharCode"))
                                valuteObject.setCharCode(text);
                            else if (property.getTagName().equals("Nominal"))
                                valuteObject.setNominal(text);
                            else if (property.getTagName().equals("Name"))
                                valuteObject.setName(text);
                            else if (property.getTagName().equals("Value"))
                                valuteObject.setValue(text);
                        }
                    }
                    valuteValues.add(valuteObject);
                }
                String sql = "insert into VALUTE (NumCode, CharCode, Nominal, Name," +
                        "Value) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
                Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://localhost/smartsoft?user=postgres&password=alberto&ssl=true");
                PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement(sql);

                for (Valute valuteValue : valuteValues) {
                    ps.setString(1, "NumCode");
                    ps.setString(2, "CharCode");
                    ps.setString(3, "Nominal");
                    ps.setString(4, "Name");
                    ps.setString(5, "Value");
                    ps.executeUpdate();
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return "main";
```

Вот entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "VALUTE")
public class Valute {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer ID;
    private String NumCode;
    private String CharCode;
    private String Nominal;
    private String Name;
    private String Value;


    public Integer getID() {
        return ID;
    }

    public void setID(Integer ID) {
        this.ID = ID;
    }

    public void setNumCode(String numCode) {
        NumCode = numCode;
    }

    public void setCharCode(String charCode) {
        CharCode = charCode;
    }

    public void setNominal(String nominal) {
        Nominal = nominal;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        Name = name;
    }

    public void setValue(String value) {
        Value = value;
    }

    public String getNumCode() {
        return NumCode;
    }

    public String getCharCode() {
        return CharCode;
    }

    public String getNominal() {
        return Nominal;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return Name;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return Value;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Valute{" +
                "NumCode='" + NumCode + '\'' +
                ", CharCode='" + CharCode + '\'' +
                ", Nominal='" + Nominal + '\'' +
                ", Name='" + Name + '\'' +
                ", Value='" + Value + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Comment: А что именно не работает при записи в бд?

Comment: Таблица создается, а данные в нее не записываются

Comment: Попробуй запустить в дебаггере и посмотреть, доходит ли вообще до выполнения кода с добавлением записей. И кстати в цикле, где ты устанавливаешь значения для PreparedStatement, ты должен передавать не строку с названием столбца, а значение того объекта, который щас в этой итерации (т.е. `valuteValue`), и уже из этого объекта доставать данные, по типу `valuteValue.getNominal()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А зачем тут цикл

```
           for (Valute valuteValue : valuteValues) {
                ps.setString(1, "NumCode");
                ps.setString(2, "CharCode");
                ps.setString(3, "Nominal");
                ps.setString(4, "Name");
                ps.setString(5, "Value");
                ps.executeUpdate();
            }
```

Уберите его и команда должна выполнится один раз. И вставьте нужные значения из xml.

Думаю у вас должно было быть что то такое

```
    String sql = "insert into valute (num_code, char_code, nominal, name," +
                    "value) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
    Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://localhost/smartsoft?user=postgres&password=alberto&ssl=true");
    

    for (Valute valuteValue : valuteValues) {
                PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
                ps.setString(1, valuteValue.getNumCode());
                ps.setString(2, valuteValue.getCharCode());
                ps.setString(3, valuteValue.getNominal());
                ps.setString(4, valuteValue.getName());
                ps.setString(5, valuteValue.getValue());
                ps.executeUpdate();
            }
```

Вне цикла

```
for (int i = 0; i < valuteList.getLength(); i++)
```

Для начала сохраните хотя бы одну запись без цикла

```
            PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
            ps.setString(1, valuteValues.get(0).getNumCode());
            ps.setString(2, valuteValues.get(0).getCharCode());
            ps.setString(3, valuteValues.get(0).getNominal());
            ps.setString(4, valuteValues.get(0).getName());
            ps.setString(5, valuteValues.get(0).getValue());
            ps.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: А как без него?

Comment: Всё просто вынесите из цикла парсинга сохранение. И сохраняйте отдельно своим циклом

Comment: Посмотрите внимательно у вас цикл парсинга совмещён с сохранением.

Comment: Исправил, данные по прежнему не сохраняются, но все равно спасибо:)

Comment: А вы сохраните для начала один элемент valuteValue. То есть чтобы команда дошла до базы данных.

Comment: Просто препаре статемент он один а в цикле сохраняется несколько раз. Так что для начала один раз сохраните. Сделайте так чтобы в xml была одна запись для сохранения

Comment: Я немного подправил ещё разок

Comment: ps.setString(1, valuteValues.get(0).toString()); так тоже не сохраняет

Comment: Совсем не то. Я показал как

Comment: Не записывает(((

Comment: Давайте посмотрим)